# How to open multiple Android Studio projects AND have each use a different SDK path?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, sdk

I currently have two Android Studio projects open, each in their separate window. I need each of them to use a different SDK path. Currently, when I change the SDK path for project 1, it automatically sets project 2 to the same SDK path. Is there a way to have these two projects open and be pointing to two, different SDK paths?

Answer (score 0):

Create `local.properties` file inside the root folder of you project and add the next line:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Path\\To\\My\\Custom\\Android\\Sdk
```

Note - This is OS specific path syntax that works for **windows**.

Comment: I already have the `local.properties` file created in the root folder. This path is automatically edited in both windows when I open up the project structure window and change the SDK path. Manually changing the SDK path in this file does not work correctly either (I've already tried this).

Comment: You have setting.gradle file in your project? @user2238415